# How to refresh GridView's data after update or delete operation in case of , GridControl.datasource = Datatable in Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridview that is related to a table in a sql server database.  I am trying to refresh the gridview right after performing a delete but nothing I've tried so far has worked.  (I've verified that the delete operation has worked in the table).  I've tried 3 ways of updating the gridview but nothing has worked:

```vb
GridControl1.Refresh()

GridView1.RefreshData()

GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()

GridView1.RefreshEditor(True)
```

Here is the complete code of the whole operation:

```vb
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(FrmGeneralConfig.GetInstance.getConnection())
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        Dim daDelete As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Client_Excepte_Charge_Min WHERE ClientNo = @ClientNo", cnn)       
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientNo", clientNo)
        daDelete.DeleteCommand = command
        daDelete.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        GridControl1.Refresh()
        GridView1.RefreshData()
        GridView1.RefreshEditor(True)
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Are you using the [GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControlMembersTopicAll) or the [GridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewMembersTopicAll)?

Comment: Both.  The GridView is in the GridControl.

Comment: I think that `GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()` should work.

Comment: I just edited my question.  I had tried 'GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()'

Comment: What is the DataSource for the GridControl? A DataTable?

Comment: @Brendon Yes.  'GridControl1.DataSource = dtExceptions' (which is a DataTable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `DataTable` after deleting the rows in server.
Here is example:

```
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(FrmGeneralConfig.GetInstance.getConnection())
    Try
        cnn.Open()

        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Client_Excepte_Charge_Min WHERE ClientNo = @ClientNo", cnn)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientNo", clientNo)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        dtExceptions.Clear()

        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
            Dim selectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Client_Excepte_Charge_Min", cnn)

            adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand
            adapter.Fill(dtExceptions)
        End Using

        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
```